# Getting the HTML code of a webpage

Tags: c#, web-crawler

I am trying to get the HTML code of a webpage using it's url. I have written the following code, it works, but comparing the resulting string it doesn't match the code I see when I use google chrome's inspect. I am not an HTML gru, but it seems to be different.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/leagues/standings/517292/classic");

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));

string PageScript = stream.ReadToEnd();
```

The resulting script is as follows: https://ideone.com/DXzfKy

I am using those two lines to set the security protocol

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

If someone can tell me what am I looking at and what might be wrong, I will be grateful.

Comment: "it seems to be different." in what way?

Comment: One thing you want to do is to dispose the Stream in a `using` block or suchlike. You'll have to declare `PageScript` outside the block though.

Comment: @DStanley I dunno how to describe tho, but I am searching for a certain block that I can see in the inspection code but it doesn't exit in the output string. I have provided a link for the output string, and if you can kindly use the url to inspect the code and see for yourself.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I do close the stream, but it's not shown in the code snippet I have used here. But would that cause such problem?

Comment: You have to consider that the page could be rendering dynamic HTML after loading in the browser. Which means that a simple get request will not GET the final HTML state.

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders The page I am trying to get its html contains a table of links, I am interested on grabbing those links for further use. The website doesn't have an API. Is there is a better way to do it?

Comment: First, I would verify that the page is indeed rendering the table of links after the page load. If that is the case, it can't be done with a simple web request, because you have to support javascript execution. But you still can do it by using a tool like CasperJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to create an instance of a WebClient and using that you can read the data from URI, than convert it into StreamReader and finally in Plain Text Format.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream dataFromPage = client.OpenRead(new Uri("https://ideone.com/DXzfKy"));
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataFromPage);
string htmlContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
```